# connecting multiple signals to

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt

I am currently working on a control system GUI, and have run into a roadblock when it comes to storing and accessing data accross threads. Currently, I am reading the pressure from a gauge, and updating a LCD display in the UI, which works fine. This issue that I have run into is when I am trying to control my system. I need to access the pressure gauges data for my control loop in real time while updating the pressure display simultaneously, but if I try to two commands (Control feedback, and display) to the gauge at the same time, I get a serial read error. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a good way to have a function just read in the data from the gauge, store it, and send the data to the pressure display and the control function whenever necessary. Here is the simplified code that I have:

## Class MainWindow():

```
#has a bunch of buttons and images that are used
#Define the threading object
self.obj=Reader.worker()
self.thread=QThread()
self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)

def PresDisplay(self,i):
     self.presNumber.display("%s", i)

def on_presReadButton_clicked(self):
     self.obj.intReady.connect(self.presDisplay)
     self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.collector)
     self.thread.start()
```

This section of the code all works very well. However, from here I am somewhat lost as to what I should do. In my worker class, I have the following:
#

## Class Worker(QObject):

```
  intReady=pyqtSignal(str)
  pres=pyqtSignal(str)

  def collector(self):
    while True:
        i=gauge.check()   #read the pressure from the gauge
        self.pres.connect(self.presSender)
        self.pres.emit(i)

  def presSender(self,i):
        self.intReady.emit(i)

  def control(self, setpoint, i):
     #This method must take in the pressure setpoint from the main GUi thread and use the pressure readings from collector at any given time to conduct the close loop control. It will be initiated from the click of a button (not the pressure read button above)
```

I understand that this is a very open ended question, but there are probably numerous ways to go about solving it.

If anyone has any ideas, I am open to giving them a try. I have been trying to solve this problem for the greater part of three weeks now.

Comment: Why are you connecting a signal on the worker to itself just to emit another signal with the same argument?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to keep reconnecting a signal on every iteration of the loop.  It's going to create duplicate connections and the same callback is going to be called multiple times each time you emit the signal

```
while True:
    i=gauge.check() 
    self.pres.connect(self.presSender) # This is bad
    self.pres.emit(i)
```

You generally only want to connect a signal once, and usually in the `__init__` method.  In this case, you're emitting a signal (`pres`) just to emit another signal with the exact same arguments (`intReady`).  Just get rid of the `pres` signal and emit `intReady` directly from the `collector` method.

```
while True:
    i=gauge.check()   #read the pressure from the gauge
    self.intReady.emit(i)
```

Also, I'm not sure how long `gauge.check()` takes to respond, but you may want to insert a `sleep` on each iteration so you're not constantly spamming the main thread with millions of signals when you only need a resolution of like 1-10 hz.

```
while True:
    i=gauge.check()   #read the pressure from the gauge
    self.intReady.emit(i)
    QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)
```

The same thing goes for the main thread.  You probably don't want to connect the signal and re-start the thread *every* time the button is pushed.  Either move everything inside the `on_click` handler into the `__init__` method, or do a check to only connect the signal and start the thread if it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You are absolutely correct, and I have changed the connections to the main threads. I am still curious if there is a good way to connect multiple signals to a single slot though.

Comment: You can connect multiple signals to a single slot, it just has to make sense.  For instance, you might have a single `refresh` function for your widget.  You could connect multiple "onChanged" signals to that one slot, so when any widget changes values, it updates the whole widget.